# Trouble with authorization request

Tags: php, sinch

I am trying to make a conferenceCallout request in Sinch service but i am having troubles with the signature. I paste the code:

```
<?php 
//JSon Object
$conferencia['method']="conferenceCallout";
$participante['cli']="46000000000";
$destination['type']="username";
$destination['endpoint']="roke1";
$participante['destination']=$destination;
$participante['domain']="mxp";
$participante['custom']="customData";
$participante['locale']="en-US";
$participante['greeting']="Welcome to my conference";
$participante['conferenceId']="conferencia_de_prueba";
$participante["enableDice"]=false;

$conferencia['conferenceCallout']=$participante;

$data=json_encode($conferencia);



$md5_body = base64_encode ( MD5 ( utf8_encode ( json_encode($conferencia) ) ) );

$applicationKey="XXXXXX-xXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX";
$applicationSecret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==";

$timestamp = new DateTime('NOW');

$StringToSign ="POST
        ".$md5_body."
        application/json
        x-timestamp:".$timestamp->format(DateTime::ISO8601)."
        /v1/callouts";

$utf8encode=utf8_encode($StringToSign);
$hash= hash_hmac("sha256",$applicationSecret,$utf8encode);
$base64=base64_encode($hash);

$Signature =$base64;
$Autorization = "Application"." ".$applicationKey.":".$Signature;


$ch = curl_init('https://callingapi.sinch.com/v1/callouts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization:' . $Autorization,
        'X-Timestamp: ' . $timestamp->format(DateTime::ISO8601),
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
        );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

But i am getting error code 40102 that is 40102 - Invalid Signature.

Can anyone help me? What i am doing wrong?

Best Regards.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `\n` between the strings you are signing.  They show it as `StringToSign = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
    Content-MD5 + "\n" +
    Content-Type + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedHeaders + "\n" +
    CanonicalizedResource;`

Comment: I try with \n and \r and did not work :(

Comment: When base64 encoding the MD5 hash and HMAC you need to be encoding the raw output:  `$md5 = base64_encode(md5($message, true));`  `base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $applicationSecret, true));`

Comment: I think is the same if you did not write the true, is by default because i get the same output. Now i get: $md5_body = base64_encode ( md5 ( utf8_encode ( json_encode($conferencia) ) ),true ); $Signature =  base64_encode(hash_hmac ("sha256", $applicationSecret, utf8_encode ( $StringToSign ),true ) ) ; But still not working

Comment: In the md5 example, the `true` is not in the right function, it got passed to base64_encode instead of md5.  By default md5 and hash_hmac do not return raw output which is what you need to pass to base64 encode.

Comment: Sorry drew010 but now i am losing about your explanation. Can you write how will be this line of code?  $Signature =  base64_encode(hash_hmac ("sha256", $applicationSecret, utf8_encode ( $StringToSign ),true ) ) ;

Comment: `$md5 = base64_encode(md5(json_encode($message), true));` & `$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $applicationSecret, true));`

Comment: Drew010 thank you for your comments but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

From their [API documentation](https://www.sinch.com/using-rest/#protectedresources), I was able to create this code which generates a signature that matches what they have.  You should be able to modify it to get it working with your code.

```
<?php

$applicationKey    = '5F5C418A0F914BBC8234A9BF5EDDAD97';
$applicationSecret = 'JViE5vDor0Sw3WllZka15Q==';

$ts        = '2014-06-04T13:41:58Z';
$resource  = '/v1/sms/+46700000000';
$timestamp = new DateTime($ts);

$body = [
    'message' => 'Hello world',
];

$message = json_encode($body);

$md5 = base64_encode(md5($message, true));

$timestamp = $ts;

$stringToSign = "POST\n" .
                $md5 . "\n" .
                "application/json\n" .
                'x-timestamp:' . $timestamp . "\n" .
                $resource;

$signature = base64_encode(
                 hash_hmac('sha256',
                           $stringToSign,
                           base64_decode($applicationSecret),
                           true
                 )
              );

echo $md5 . "\n" . $signature . "\n";
// jANzQ+rgAHyf1MWQFSwvYw==
// qDXMwzfaxCRS849c/2R0hg0nphgdHciTo7OdM6MsdnM=
```

Answer (score 1):

I post the code that work to me.

```
$phone ="+460000000" //Put the destination number here
$key = "XXXXXX";    
$secret = "XXXXXX"; 
$message = $first_name . ', thanks you for signing in. We will text you when we\'re ready for you';
$phone   = $phone_number;

$body = json_encode(array('From' => $rented_number, 'Message'=>$message, ));

$timestamp = date("c");

$path                  = "/v1/sms".$phone;
$content_type          = "application/json";
$canonicalized_headers = "x-timestamp:" . $timestamp;

$content_md5 = base64_encode( md5( utf8_encode($body), true ));

$string_to_sign =
    "POST\n".
    $content_md5."\n".
    $content_type."\n".
    $canonicalized_headers."\n".
    $path;

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), base64_decode($secret), true));
$authorization = "Application " . $key . ":" . $signature;

$service_url = 'https://messagingapi.sinch.com'.$path;
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'content-type: '.$content_type,
    'x-timestamp:' . $timestamp,
    'authorization:' . $authorization
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
// @todo: checking response / working with results
curl_close($curl);
```

Thank drew010 to your help, was amazing!!