# Sinch voice callback request signin

Tags: php, sinch

I'm making app-to-phone app using Sinch.
I'm successfully providing the callback for ICE and ACE event without request signin.
But now, when I try to sign the request to make it more secure, it always fails to meet the requirement

I get my code from here : [Trouble with authorization request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789768/trouble-with-authorization-request)

It works when I try to use data and application key from https://www.sinch.com/using-rest/#callbackrequestsigning

But when I try to use real data, it always fail.

```
    $key = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx";    
    $secret = 'my-app-secret';

    $body = $request->getContent();

    $timestamp = $request->input('timestamp');

    $path                  = '/sinch/callback/' . $callbackType;
    $content_type          = "application/json";
    $canonicalized_headers = "x-timestamp:" . $timestamp;

    $content_md5 = base64_encode( md5( utf8_encode($body), true ));

    $string_to_sign =
        "POST\n".
        $content_md5."\n".
        $content_type."\n".
        $canonicalized_headers."\n".
        $path;

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), base64_decode($secret), true));

    $authorizationHeader = $request->header('Authorization');
    $sinchAuthorizationHeader = str_replace('Application ', '', $authorizationHeader);
    $sinchAuthorizationHeader = explode(':', $sinchAuthorizationHeader);

    if($sinchAuthorizationHeader[0] == $key && $signature == $sinchAuthorizationHeader[1]) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789768/trouble-with-authorization-request

Comment: Hi @cjensen, as I described in my question. I got my code from that thread.